# How to get all my parsed data in an array rather than in separate lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the table listing [String Method at the end of the page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp) but got stuck in the final step. 
This is how I did:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = soup.table
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in rows:
  td = tr.find_all('td')
  row = [i.text for i in td]
  print(row)
```

But here is the O/P I am getting:

[image: Screenshot: But here is the O/P I am getting]

How can I get that in an array so that it would be easy for me to turn it into df? Any other suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Hope this helps!

Minor change to your for loop code

```py
>>> data = []
>>> len(rows)
45
>>> for tr in rows:
...   td = tr.find_all('td')
...   row = [i.text for i in td]
...   if row:
...     data.append(row)
```

1. Created a new variable called `data` to store your collected info. This is a list data types object (In pythons, its similar to an array but not limited with size & you can add all types data to it).
2. Added an `if row` condition. So this row has no values found, then that empty list is not added to `data`
3. Below is how you make your dataframe

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['first', 'second'])
>>> df.head()
          first                                             second
0  capitalize()  Converts the first \r\n    character to upper ...
1    casefold()            Converts string into \r\n    lower case
2      center()                  Returns a centered \r\n    string
3       count()  Returns the number of \r\n    times a specifie...
4      encode()   Returns an encoded \r\n    version of the string
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I really appreciate your precious time for letting me know where I was wrong.

Comment: BTW, I tried to eliminate \r\n using this code and it worked: df=df.replace({r'\r\n': ''}, regex=True)
But I wanna know if there is any other way to do so? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When I ever I see `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags, I go straight to pandas (it uses BeautifulSoup under the hood). It'll do the hard work for you and cleans it up a bit:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings.asp"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
            Method                                        Description
0     capitalize()         Converts the first character to upper case
1       casefold()                    Converts string into lower case
2         center()                          Returns a centered string
3          count()  Returns the number of times a specified value ...
4         encode()           Returns an encoded version of the string
5       endswith()  Returns true if the string ends with the speci...
6     expandtabs()                    Sets the tab size of the string
7           find()  Searches the string for a specified value and ...
8         format()               Formats specified values in a string
9     format_map()               Formats specified values in a string
10         index()  Searches the string for a specified value and ...
11       isalnum()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
12       isalpha()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
13     isdecimal()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
14       isdigit()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
15  isidentifier()        Returns True if the string is an identifier
16       islower()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
17     isnumeric()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
18   isprintable()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
19       isspace()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
20       istitle()  Returns True if the string follows the rules o...
21       isupper()  Returns True if all characters in the string a...
22          join()  Joins the elements of an iterable to the end o...
23         ljust()     Returns a left justified version of the string
24         lower()                  Converts a string into lower case
25        lstrip()          Returns a left trim version of the string
26     maketrans()  Returns a translation table to be used in tran...
27     partition()  Returns a tuple where the string is parted int...
28       replace()  Returns a string where a specified value is re...
29         rfind()  Searches the string for a specified value and ...
30        rindex()  Searches the string for a specified value and ...
31         rjust()    Returns a right justified version of the string
32    rpartition()  Returns a tuple where the string is parted int...
33        rsplit()  Splits the string at the specified separator, ...
34        rstrip()         Returns a right trim version of the string
35         split()  Splits the string at the specified separator, ...
36    splitlines()  Splits the string at line breaks and returns a...
37    startswith()  Returns true if the string starts with the spe...
38         strip()            Returns a trimmed version of the string
39      swapcase()  Swaps cases, lower case becomes upper case and...
40         title()  Converts the first character of each word to u...
41     translate()                        Returns a translated string
42         upper()                  Converts a string into upper case
43         zfill()  Fills the string with a specified number of 0 ...
```

Comment: OMG! I never thought I would get it in just three lines of code! Incredible indeed! Thanks for a valuable lesson!:)